# Camera/Gallery Button in One scene, Image in Another

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, camera, uiimageview

I'm new to Swift and iOS programming so please bear with me.

Right now I have 2 scenes, View Controller and Edit Photo.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dtq23.jpg)

In View Controller I have 2 buttons, one to take a photo using the iPhone's camera and another to choose a photo from the gallery. The code works where if I press either button it functions properly. However, my problem is where the image is sent after it has been taken/selected.

What I want it to do is after the user takes the photo or selects it from the gallery, I want the image to have it's own view so that it can be edited afterwards. I'm creating a meme app, so I want the image to have the screen to itself.

This is what I can't get working. I can put a UIImageView on the same view as the buttons and it works that way, but I can't make the image go onto its own view.

View Controller Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationBarDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
{

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

//Opens the camera
@IBAction func openCameraButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//Opens the photo gallery
@IBAction func openGalleryButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The code below is what I want in the new view. I tried creating an outlet from the ImageView to the EditPhoto.swift file, but the scenes don't connect afterwards.

```
//Saves the image
@IBOutlet weak var imagePicked: UIImageView!

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    imagePicked.image = image
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. And if I'm going about this all wrong, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I have objective-c code, its working fine if you want i post the answer and you get the idea then convert the code in swift

Comment: @lyyappan Ravi yeah I would appreciate it. thank you.

Comment: i post the objective C code?

Answer (score 0):

My code is Objective C, i post its, you will get the idea and its working for me, camera image and gallery image,

imageAddView is `UIImageView`,

my gallery get image method is below,

```
-(void)addphotos
{
    UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photoPicker.delegate = self;
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    photoPicker.allowsEditing= YES;

    [self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    isCaptureImage = NO;
}
```

My camera capture method is below,

```
-(void) TakeNewphoto
{
    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }
    else
    {
        UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        photoPicker.delegate = self;
        photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        photoPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        photoPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        isCaptureImage = YES;
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)photoPicker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType;
    mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];


    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage ])
    {
        if (isCaptureImage == NO)
        {
            ALAssetsLibrary *library = [ALAssetsLibrary new];

            [library assetForURL:[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                ALAssetRepresentation *original = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                UIImage *myimag = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[original fullScreenImage] scale:[original scale] orientation:0];
                imageAddView.image = [UIImage squareImageWithImage:myimag scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(640, 640)];
            } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"Failed to load captured image.");
            }];

            [photoPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
        }
        else
        {
            UIImage * image = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
            imageAddView.image  = [UIImage squareImageWithImage:image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(640, 640)];

            [photoPicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
        }

    }

}
```

hope its helpful.